# java compare comma separated string

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, split

I'm trying to compare the comma separated string in java. If it consists of all days of the week, return true

```
import java.util.Arrays;

String scheduleDays="Wed,Tue,Mon,Thu,Sun,Fri,Sat";

if (Arrays.equals(Arrays.sort(scheduleDays.split(",")), ['Fri', 'Mon',  'Sat', 'Sun', 'Thu', 'Tue', 'Wed']){
    return true;
}
 else {
   return false
 }
```

Is there a quicker way to compare it, I thought of using sort method to compare with sorted days of the week.

It seems that above doesn't seems to work, will try research more.

Comment: Does `'Fri'` even compile?

Comment: it doesn't compile. tried  String[] sortedArray = new String[]{'Fri', 'Mon', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Thu', 'Tue', 'Wed'};

Comment: Exactly. Java uses `'` for `char`'s, not `String`'s. Use `"` instead: `new String[]{"Fri", "Mon"...};`

Comment: seems that it is complaining below line during compile time
String[] dayStrArray = Arrays.sort(scheduleDays.split(","));

Comment: Did you check to docs for `Arrays.sort()`?

Comment: yes,  will change to using  containsAll functanility instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than sorting arrays, it's cleaner to use a `List<String>` as your baseline, and just use `containsAll()` to check.

Something like this might work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(checkDays("Wed,Tue,Mon,Thu,Sun,Fri,Sat")); // true
    System.out.println(checkDays("Tue,Mon,Thu,Sun,Fri,Sat"));     // false
}

static List<String> allDays = Arrays.asList("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");
public static boolean checkDays(String days) {
    return Arrays.asList(days.split(",")).containsAll(allDays);
}
```